# Rearranging UL list without using appendChild on all LI elements

Tags: javascript

I could use some help on the correct way to approach this. Effectively, I'm trying to regularly update various UL elements without using appendChild on the entire list as that will cause the browser to lose focus (if for example the user has something highlighted to copy and paste). I feel like I've overcomplicated my approach, but it's been stumping me and I'm not sure i can figure out something better.
I have an ordered array from the data source, and I have my UL that may need new items or remove old items to match the ordered array. By removing all LI elements then appending the valid list in order, I accomplish this. Please note that the following is very minimal to represent the nature of the question as my original code has a lot more bloat.

```
<BODY>
    <UL id="list">
        <LI class="listItem" data-name="john">red</LI>
        <LI class="listItem" data-name="mark">green</LI>
        <LI class="listItem" data-name="jane">yellow</LI>
        <LI class="listItem" data-name="suzie">orange</LI>
    </UL>
</BODY>
```

The javascript I first used was similar to:

```
let updatedArray = [
    {name: "john", colour: "red"},
    {name: "phil", colour: "blue"},
    {name: "jane", colour: "orange"},
    {name: "suzie", colour: "orange"},
    {name: "casey", colour: "purple"},
];

let list = document.getElementById("list");
let currentItems = Array.from(list.querySelectorAll(".listItem"));
let orderedItems = [];

updatedArray.forEach( (updatedItem) => {
    let currentItem = currentItems.find( item => item.dataset.name == updatedItem.name);

    if(currentItem != null) {
        if(currentItem.textContent != updatedItem.colour) currentItem.textContent = updatedItem.colour;
    } else {
        currentItem = document.createElement("LI");
        currentItem.dataset.name = updatedItem.name;
        currentItem.textContent = updatedItem.colour;
    }

    orderedItems.push(currentItem);
});

for(let i=list.children.length; i > 0; i--) {
    list.removeChild(list.lastChild);
}

for(let i=0, n=orderedItems.length; i < n; i++) {
    list.appendChild(orderedItems[i]);
}
```

I think there are different ways to improve the above, but the crux of my problem is using appendChild to relist everything in the correct order, as that also removes focus. What I've been trying to do instead is to compare the two arrays, but it takes a number of steps and seems like a poor approach (and not yet thoroughly tested):

```
let updatedArray = [
    {name: "john", colour: "red"},
    {name: "phil", colour: "blue"},
    {name: "jane", colour: "orange"},
    {name: "suzie", colour: "orange"},
    {name: "casey", colour: "purple"},
];

let list = document.getElementById("list");
let currentItems = Array.from(list.querySelectorAll(".listItem"));
let orderedItems = [];

updatedArray.forEach( (updatedItem) => {
    let index = currentItems.findIndex( item => item.dataset.name == updatedItem.name);

    if(index > -1) {
        if(currentItems[index].textContent != updatedItem.colour) currentItems[index].textContent = updatedItem.colour;

        // Remove found items to identify unmatched elements.
        currentItems.splice(index);
    } else {
        currentItem = document.createElement("LI");
        currentItem.dataset.name = updatedItem.name;
        currentItem.textContent = updatedItem.colour;
    }

    orderedItems.push(currentItem);
});

// currentItems array now represents LI elements to be delisted. These are removed.
currentItems.forEach( (delistedItem) => {
    delistedItem.parentNode.removeChild(delistedItem);
})

for(let i=0, n=orderedItems.length; i < n; i++) {
    if(orderedItems[i] != list.children[i]) {
        // Check if at the end of the current list already, or need to insert into list.
        if(i >= list.children.length-1) {
            list.appendChild(orderedItems[i]);
        } else {
            list.insertBefore(orderedItems[i], list.children[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get much (or any) response to the question, so for now I've come up with a generic use function for my above needs. Not sure if it's worth sharing, but I will nonetheless if it can help anyone else.

The function essentially works in three steps:

1. Form a list of updated list elements and elements to be delisted (items not found in the source).
2. Iterate through delisted array and remove them from the list container.
3. Iterate through the updated array, and append new items or re-append items in the wrong position in the container at the correct position based on this array.

Since the source data is arbitrary, it's up to the user to identify how the source uniquely correlates to the list element by supplying functions for checking the identity and creating a new LI element with that identity. For example, the function for `funcs.funcNewItem` could set the id attribute or a data-id attribute, and `funcs.funcCheckIdentity` can check they match.

Advice, corrections, or criticisms welcome. This functionality solves my current dilemma, but I can appreciate any way to improve.

Full code using the example in the question:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @template {HTMLLIElement} LISTELEM
 * @template {HTMLUListElement|HTMLMenuElement} LISTCONTAINER
 * @param {Array<T>} sourceArray
 * @param {LISTCONTAINER} listContainer
 * @param {string | null} containerQuerySelector
 * @param {Object} funcs
 * @param {function(T, LISTELEM): Boolean} funcs.funcCheckIdentity
 * @param {function(T): LISTELEM} funcs.funcNewItem
 * @param {function(T, LISTELEM): Void | null} funcs.funcModifyItem
 * @param {function(LISTELEM): Void | null} funcs.funcDeleteItem
 * @return {Array<LISTELEM>}
 */
function SyncHTMLList(sourceArray, listContainer, containerQuerySelector, funcs) {
    if(!Array.isArray(sourceArray)) {
        throw new TypeError("SyncHTMLList : Bad argument for sourceArray");
    } else if (listContainer == null || !(listContainer instanceof Element)) {
        throw new TypeError("SyncHTMLList : Bad argument for listContainer");
    } else if ( funcs == null
        || typeof funcs.funcCheckIdentity !== "function" 
        || typeof funcs.funcNewItem !== "function" 
        ) {
        throw new TypeError("SyncHTMLList : Bad argument for funcs");
    }

    //  Apply correct method for retrieving current live list of list elements.
    let GetListElementsArray = (containerQuerySelector && typeof containerQuerySelector === "string")
        ? () => Array.from(listContainer.querySelectorAll(containerQuerySelector))
        : () => Array.from(listContainer.children)
    ;

    /**@type {Array<LISTELEM>} Copy of existing list as potential delist array, and splice as items are found in source. */
    let delistedItems = GetListElementsArray();
    
    /**@type {Array<LISTELEM>} New list, updated from source array. */
    let orderedItems = [];

    for(let i=0, n=sourceArray.length; i<n; i++) {
        // Look for associated LI element using comparison function "funcCheckIdentity"
        let itemIndex = delistedItems.findIndex( listElement => funcs.funcCheckIdentity(sourceArray[i], listElement) );

        /**@type {LISTITEM} Current LI Element (whether found or created) */
        let listElement = null;

        //  If associated LI element found in container, associate to variable and remove from delist array.
        //  Otherwise create element.
        if (itemIndex < 0) {
            listElement = funcs.funcNewItem(sourceArray[i]);
        } else {
            listElement = delistedItems[itemIndex];
            delistedItems.splice(itemIndex,1);
        }

        //  Make any checks/modifcations specified by user on item.
        if (funcs.funcModifyItem) funcs.funcModifyItem(sourceArray[i], listElement);

        //  Add list element to final ordered list.
        orderedItems.push(listElement);
    }

    //  Remove unfound LI elements from container, with user specified function if available.
    if (funcs.funcDeleteItem && typeof funcs.funcDeleteItem === "function") {
        delistedItems.forEach( listElement => funcs.funcDeleteItem(listElement) );
    } else {
        delistedItems.forEach( listElement => listElement.parentNode.removeChild(listElement) );
    }

    //  Reorganize list in DOM according to sourceArray/orderedItems.
    for (let i=0, n=orderedItems.length; i < n; i++) {
        let liveList = GetListElementsArray();

        if(orderedItems[i] != liveList[i]) {
            if(i >= liveList.length-1) {
                listContainer.appendChild(orderedItems[i]);
            } else {
                listContainer.insertBefore(orderedItems[i], liveList[i+1]);
            }
        }
    }

    //  Return an array of the list elements.
    return orderedItems;
}

var updateButton = document.getElementById("btnUpdate");
updateButton.addEventListener( 'click'
,   (event) => {
        let updatedArray = [
            {name: "john", colour: "red"},
            {name: "phil", colour: "blue"},
            {name: "jane", colour: "orange"},
            {name: "suzie", colour: "orange"},
            {name: "casey", colour: "purple"},
        ];
        
        let list = document.getElementById("list");
        let funcs = {};
        funcs.funcNewItem = (data) => {
            let el = document.createElement("LI");
            el.dataset.name = data.name;
            el.className = "listitem";
            el.textContent = data.colour;

            return el;
        }

        funcs.funcCheckIdentity = (data, element) => {
            return data.name == element.dataset.name;
        }

        funcs.funcModifyItem = (data, element) => {
            if(data.colour != element.textContent) {
                element.textContent = data.colour;
            }
        }

        SyncHTMLList(updatedArray, list, null, funcs);
    }
,   {once: true}
);
```

```html
<BODY>
    <UL id="list">
        <LI class="listItem" data-name="john">red</LI>
        <LI class="listItem" data-name="mark">green</LI>
        <LI class="listItem" data-name="jane">yellow</LI>
        <LI class="listItem" data-name="suzie">orange</LI>
    </UL>
    <BUTTON id="btnUpdate">Update</BUTTON
</BODY>
```